# How to resolve datetime issue while importing data from Sybase to SQL Server using CSV

Tags: sql-server, csv, sybase

I am to migrate data from Sybase DB to a SQL Server database using CSV upload.

I have this in the Sybase:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.employee_payments
(
    Trans_Id            numeric(12,0) IDENTITY,
    Payment_Trans_Id    varchar(40)   NOT NULL,
    Acct_No             char(12)      NOT NULL,
    Amount              decimal(21,6) NOT NULL,
    Status              varchar(12)   NOT NULL,
    Create_Date         datetime      NOT NULL,
    Process_Date        datetime      NULL
);
```

I exported all the data into CSV

**CSV Sample:**

```
Trans_Id,Payment_Trans_Id,Acct_No,Amount,Status,Create_Date,Process_Date

21941014,230426034338050436,2052081969  ,2000.000000,PROCESSED,26/04/2023 12:00:57.016,26/04/2023 12:01:16.713, 

21941015,230426034338053487,2544698415  ,9000.000000,PENDING,26/04/2023 12:01:03.276,,

21941016,230426034336130371,2391109917  ,200.000000,PENDING,26/04/2023 12:01:22.026,, 

21941017,230426034338070418,2544698415  ,9000.000000,PENDING,26/04/2023 12:01:40.316,,
```

In SQL Server, I created the table in order to import the data from CSV:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.employee_payments
(
    Trans_Id            numeric(12,0) IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Payment_Trans_Id    varchar(40)   NOT NULL,
    Acct_No             char(12)      NOT NULL,
    Amount              decimal(21,6) NOT NULL,
    Status              varchar(12)   NOT NULL,
    Create_Date         datetime      NOT NULL,
    Process_Date        datetime      NULL
);
```

In order to import the CSV file, I launched SSMS version 18. I right click on the database, and click "File -> Import Data".

I then choose "Flat File Source" as the data source, and click on "Next", browse and select the `.CSV` file.

Then for the Create_Date and Process_Date, I went to advanced and selected database timestamp [DT_DBTIMESTAMP] for the datatype -> Next

For Destination, I chose OLEDB Provider For SQL Server -> Next

However, when I finally submitted, it fails flags the columns with dates (Create_Date and Process_Date).

I got this error:

> Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for
> column "Create_Date" returned status value 2 and status text "The
> value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".
>      (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

I think is that the way Sybase structures its datetime is different from SQL Server.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: 26/04/2023 is not a great format, you should've used YYYYMMDD one. Now, i think the best thing to do is to import the dates as text and then do conversion to datetime in code

Comment: Import your data first into a staging table in TempDB then you can query the data, transform as required, and insert into the target table.

Comment: [Converting Between Strings and Date/Time Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/integration-services-data-types#converting-between-strings-and-datetime-data-types) recommends the `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fff]` format for `DT_DBTIMESTAMP` types, although you might still want a `T` separator between the date and time portions to avoid conversion errors cause by `DATEFORMAT` differences in the connected SQL session.

Comment: Can you redo the export from your Sybase table so its `datetime` columns are formatted as `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` If you do your sql server import will go much better.

Comment: @siggemannen - I am not the one that created the Sybase DB, so I don't have control over it

Comment: @O.Jones - How do I active that? I just exported to CSV straight using DBArtisan

Comment: You haven't told us anything about your export workflow. Ask your database administrator if you have one, or ask another question here describing how you get the Sybase data into a file.

Comment: @O.Jones - I access the Sybase DB with DBArtisan. And for the export. after using select * from tablename, I selected the whole data, right click, click on save. Then I save it as   *.csv                       You can see the sample from the posted code

Comment: if DBArtisan don't have support for better format, then you'll likely need a staging table and then do the conversion manually when importing from staging to real table

Comment: @siggemannen - How do I achieve that? Kindly assist

Comment: assuming this is Sybase ASE, why aren't you using `bcp` for both the (Sybase) extraction and (MS SQL) upload?

Comment: @markp-fuso - Yes, it is Sybase ASE. What do you mean by bcp and how do I use that?

Comment: `bcp` is an OS/command line program used to bulk copy data out-of/into ASE (see the `Utilities` manual for more details); I'm pretty sure MS SQL still supports `bcp` though its features may have changed some since the Sybase/Microsoft split (back in the 90's); you'll likely want to look at using the `-c` (character) mode; `bcp` has a lot of bells and whistles so a bit too much to go into here; `bcp` is a pretty simple/standard tool for moving data between databases so there should be plenty of hits on any web/SO search on `bcp`

Comment: another option to consider would be proxy tables (that's ASE's name; not sure what MS SQL calls them); you setup a link between the databases which allows for the use of standard SQL/DML statements (eg, insert/select, select/into) to move data between databases

Comment: Microsoft makes a software for this migration .... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/sybase/sql-server-migration-assistant-for-sybase-sybasetosql?view=sql-server-ver16